# React Native Expo generate apk return error: should NOT have additional property 'googleMobileAdsAppId'

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I'm using ReactNative Expo for developing android/iOS app also added AdMOB via [expo ADMOB sdk](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/admob/) . Issue is when i generate apk using `expo build:android -t apk` . It's returning following error because of `googleMobileAdsAppId` field in `app.json` file. I'm using admob `"sdkVersion": "34.0.0"`

`Error: Problems validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/workflow/configuration/
 • Field: android.config - should NOT have additional property 'googleMobileAdsAppId'.
Couldn't publish because errors were found. (See logs above.) Please fix the errors and try again.`

Here is my `app.json` file:
`{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "slug": "AppSlug",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "34.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.x.yyyyy",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well solution was pretty simple, it was because of SDK `version: 34.0.0` . I just updated my current version to `35.0.0` and it works like a charm.
**Upgrade from SDK 34 to SDK 35:**

1. `app.json`, change `sdkVersion` to `"35.0.0"`
2. In `package.json`, change these dependencies:

`{
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
  "expo": "^35.0.0",
  "react": "16.8.3"
}`

3. Delete your project’s node_modules directory and run npm install again
4. Also run `expo r -c` and `npm cache clean -f` to avoid any cache issue.

and that's it.

Fore more info about [upgrading SDK](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)